# Write a function that returns the maximum quantity of non-zero elements between two zero elements

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

Given an array of integers I need to find the maximum quantity of non zero elements between two zero elements

For example: `int[] arr = {1,2,0,2,3,4,5,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,8,0,1}`

This should return 9. However, this returns 4:

```java
static int solution(int[] arr) {
    int count = 0;
    int maxCount = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
        if (arr[i] == 0 && i < arr.length - 2) {
            i++;
            while (arr[i] != 0) {
                count++;
                i++;
            }
            maxCount = count;
        }
    }
    return maxCount;
}
```

UPD: For the case of {1,2,3,0,0,3,2,1}, function should return 0

Comment: Step through your code with a debugger. At the point when you encounter the second `0`, you will see that you have one `i++` "too much", which makes you not enter the `while` again. Because your `while` is exited when the index points to the `0` in the array - and your `for` loop increases the index for the next loop iteration.

Comment: Furthermore, you have to initialize you variable 'count' to 0 at the beginning of the 'for' loop, otherwise you code will continue to increase the 'count' value and it will return 13 instead of 9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some issues:

- The inner loop may run `i` out of the array's range.
- When you find the *ending* zero, your code does not take into account that this zero is also the start of a new group, and "misses" it.
- `count` is never reset to zero, so it keeps increasing also when you get into a second "group"
- `maxCount` is set unconditionally, yet it should only be updated if the new count is greater than the count you already got.
- There is no provision for when there is no group at all. I would suggest to return -1 in that case, so to differentiate it from the case where there *is* a group of length 0. This -1 should then be the initial value of the counts.

Also:

- It is strange that the outer loop condition is made more strict by the `if` condition at the top of your loop. So why not make that `i< arr.length-2` the loop condition?

Here is a correction of your attempt:

```
static int solution(int[] arr) {
    int count = -1; // Start with invalid count
    int maxCount = -1;

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length - 2; i++) { // Stricter loop condition
        if (arr[i] == 0) {
            count = 0; // Reset counter
            // Safety & Look ahead for zero
            while (i + 1 < arr.length && arr[i + 1] != 0) {
                count++;
                i++;
            }
            if (i + 1 >= arr.length) break; // No ending zero found
            // Only update if improvement
            if (count > maxCount) maxCount = count;
        }
    }
    return maxCount;
}
```

You can however reduce the code a bit by using the outer loop to do the job of the inner loop:

```
static int solution(int[] arr) {
    // Start with a count that can safely increment with `++` without getting positive
    int count = -arr.length; 
    int maxCount = -1;

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] == 0) {
            if (count > maxCount) maxCount = count;
            count = 0; // Start of a potential new group
        } else {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return maxCount;
}
```

And instead of maintaining `count` you could maintain the last starting index of a group:

```
static int solution(int[] arr) {
    int start = arr.length; // Invalid start index
    int maxCount = -1;

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] == 0) {
            if (i - start > maxCount) maxCount = i - start;
            start = i + 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @IvanDvurechenskiy, I fixed that issue.

Comment: I suggest a slight improvement: if you initialize with `count= - "some large number"; maxCount= 0;`, you can dispense yourself with the test `count >= 0`. For the large number, the array length can do.

Comment: I added a version that gets rid of `count++` as well.

Answer (score 1):

This problem can be solved in a single pass. Observe the counts of non-zero elements when progressing from left to right:

```
1,2,0,2,3,4,5,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,8,0,1
- - 0 1 2 3 4 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1
```

Now consider the partial solution for the left subarray processed

```
1,2,0,2,3,4,5,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,8,0,1
- - 0 1 2 3 4 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 9 9
```

This tells you how to solve:

- keep a counter of the number of non-zero elements since the previous zero.  (Increment on nonzero, reset to zero on zero.)
- keep the "answer" updated: every time you see a zero, keep the largest of the counter and the current answer, initially zero.

For the initial elements, it suffices to keep the count negative so that it does not influence the answer. A safe option is to initialize with minus the length of the list.

---

Technically, the loop is based on an invariant expressing that the counter holds the number of numbers since the previous zero (or a negative value), while answer holds the correct answer for the subarray traversed so far.

---

```
counter= - length(list)
answer= 0
for element in list:
  if element == 0:
      answer= max(counter, answer)
      counter= 0
  else:
      counter= counter + 1
```

Answer (score 1):

This will fix your all scenario,
*Time complexity is **O(n)***

```
  public static int maxCountBwZero(int arr[]) {
        int i = 0;
        int tempCount = 0;
        int size = arr.length;
        int maxCount = 0;
        boolean startCount = false;

        while (i < size) {
            if (arr[i] == 0) {
                if (maxCount == 0 && tempCount == 0) {
                    startCount = true;
                } else {
                    if (tempCount > 0 && (tempCount >= maxCount)) {
                        maxCount = tempCount;
                    }
                    tempCount = 0;
                }
            } else if (startCount) {
                tempCount++;
            }
            i++;

        }
        return maxCount;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] arr = { 1, 2, 0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 8, 0, 1 };
        int[] arr1 = { 1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 3, 2, 1 };

        System.out.println(maxCountBwZero(arr));
        System.out.println(maxCountBwZero(arr1));
    }
```